# Bash capturing output of awk into array

Tags: linux, arrays, bash

I am stuck on a little problem. I have a command which pipes output to awk but I want to capture the output of to an array one by one.

My example:

```
myarr=$(ps -u kdride | awk '{ print $1 }')
```

But that capture all my output into one giant string separated by commas:

```
output: PID 3856 5339 6483 10448 15313 15314 15315 15316 22348 29589 29593 32657 1
```

I also tried the following:

```
IFS=","
myarr=$(ps -u kdride | awk '{ print $1"," }')

But the output is: PID, 3856, 5339, 6483, 10448, 15293, 15294, 15295, 15296, 22348, 29589, 29593, 32657,
1
```

I want to be able to capture each individual pid into its own array element. Setting `IFS = '\n'` does not do anything and retains my original output. What change do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: You can skip the `awk` command altogether by using `myarr=( $(ps -u kdride -o pid) )`. (Note the extra parenthesis as pointed out in Paul's answer).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Add additional parentheses, like this:

```
myarr=($(ps -u kdride | awk '{ print $1 }'))

# Now access elements of an array (change "1" to whatever you want)
echo ${myarr[1]}

# Or loop through every element in the array
for i in "${myarr[@]}"
do
   :
  echo $i
done
```

See also [`bash` — Arrays](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays).

Comment: Ah much thanks. I skipped over that part entirely. Reference helps much thanks

Comment: What is the point of the : after the do? Why do we need a true here? I ran it without it and it still worked?

Comment: I am also curious why there is a `:`

Comment: I am also curious why there is a : please let us know

Comment: Has anyone came to verdict on why there is a random colon?

Comment: I have used this twice recently, works like a charm. But it looks like the mystery of the superfluous colon is still unsolved.

Answer (score 5):

Use Bash's builtin [mapfile](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-mapfile) (or its synonym `readarray`)

```
mapfile -t -s 1 myarr < <(ps -u myusername | awk '{print $1}')
```

At least in GNU/Linux you can format output of `ps`, so no need for `awk` and `-s 1`

```
mapfile -t myarr < <(ps -u myusername -o pid=)
```

Comment: why do you need to use `<` twice?

Comment: @baggiponte It is because I am redirecting [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst)